# how to add a gap in a reapeating frame using a blank page in Oracle Reports Developer

Tags: oracle, report

I want to conditionally insert a blank page ina a report made with Oracle Reports Developer.
The report consists of a constant header and below that there's a repeating frame which starts on the first page and has N pages.
I want to conditionally insert a blank page on the second page page of the executed report.
It's easy when I insert it after the header and before the repeating frame.
I don't know how to make a gap in a table made by the repeating frame.

I tried inserting a small frame printed on every page, setting a line break after it and making it visible only on page 2 (using srw.get_page_number).
It doesn't work. Line break is not made and even if it was made there would be some table headers that are set in the report to be printed on every page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could insert a large, transparent, fixed size frame within the repeating frame. Make the repeating frame variable height and put a format trigger on the fixed size frame such that it only prints on the desired page.

Comment: Still there would be some table headers on the second page that are printed on every page. I will have to conditionally turn them off in format triggers. But generally it works.